# Maximum sum of contiguous subarrays where combinations of elements have a given value (netagive also )

Tags: algorithm, maximum-profit-problem

Hello I have a problem where i have eliminated to having a struct

```
struct profit
{
    int start, finish, profit;
};
```

For elements in the array this struct represents the elements from start to finish and the profit of it . (might be negative and can contain only one element )
All elements (or a subarray that contains them) must be contained in the total sum . 
I first tried with a modified version of Weighted interval selection but solving it this way , the solution cuts out all negative elements  so it does not contain all elements . 
Any other known problem I can relate to ?

Comment: can you please provide a small numeric example?

Comment: Yes 
ie profit = {(0,0,-2),(0,1,4),(0,2,-5),(1,1,2),(1,2,-6),(2,2,5),(2,3,-3),(3,3,5)}
best way to get maximum sum is combining element 0&1 with value of 4 and element 2 and element 3 on its own with each value 5. Maximum sum of values is 14.